# Cisco ASA 5515 NAT with service-group definition

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am trying to setup a load balancer behind my ASA 5515. (Running Cisco IOS version 9.1.)

Is it possible to group the ports to do a static nat, with a service-group statement?
For instance, I want to be able to NAT ports 80 and 443 (and other ports).

My service group:

```
object-group service webServices
   service-object tcp destination eq www 
   service-object tcp destination eq https
```

My network object:

```
object network lb01
   host 192.168.1.13
```

My hopeful nat statement (which fails woefully):

```
nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp object-group webServices object-group webServices
```

Please can someone correct me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed it.
Final configuration (though the ASA complained a few times about overlap) is

```
object network lb01
  host 192.168.72.11

object-group service webServices
 service-object tcp destination eq www 
 service-object tcp destination eq https

object network lb01
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface


access-list outside_in extended permit object-group webServices any object lb01
```

It works and only the ports in the service group get NAT'ed.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: I tried before but it told me I can't accept until 2 days.